# How to Show / Hide a Responsive Menu Just using CSS Pseudo Selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `nav` item, which hides a menu icon above a certain resolution and shows it under a certain resolution.  I want to make it so clicking, or touching, the menu icon shows a `nav ul` on the first touch and then clicking anywhere else, including on the icon itself, hides the `nav ul`.  Right now I have it so that clicking on the icon shows the `ul` and clicking anywhere except the header shows it.  However, clicking on the menu icon again does not hide it.  Is this possible to do without Javascript?

**HTML**

```
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menuIcon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul {
    display: none;
}

nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}

nav:active {
    display: block;
}

nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6em 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    -webkit-transition: color 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 500ms ease-out;
    transition: color 500ms ease-out;
    color: #777;
}

a:active {
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Where is your JQuery / Javascript code that handles the Click event of the icon? Could you add it to your post. It would help

Comment: The most important part: your JS part is not presented.

Comment: This was all done without Javascript.  I was wondering if it was possible to do it withouth JS

Comment: Unfortunately, the behaviour you describe does require a small amount of JavaScript to implement.

Comment: That is fine.  Am I correct that the `onTouch` event defaults to `onClick`?